# install face_recognition pakage

Tags: rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when installing face_recognition package in fuerte the following errors appear : 1 _ make[3]: * [../bin/Fserver] Error 1 2_ make[2]: [CMakeFiles/Fserver.dir/all] Error 2 3_ make[1]: ** [all] Error 2 the package name is procrob_functional-master ,,, the following command i wrote in the terminal is : rosmake procrob_functional-master i am using ubuntu 12.04 please i need an urgent help to successfully built the face recognition package

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/155781/install-face_recognition-pakage/) by [smart engineer](https://answers.ros.org/users/15051/smart-engineer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-04-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Step 1) cd procrob_functional-master/

Step 2) rosmake face_recognition

enjoy!

---

Originally posted by [adreno](https://answers.ros.org/users/4576/adreno/) with karma: 253 on 2014-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0